# No response from ebay API : findCompletedItemsRequest no response

Tags: xml, ebay-api

Below is the entire code I have been trying to use to get listings with a certain keyword and category id 293. I was first trying to get auctions that have ended but nothing worked so decided to get this basic request working(all listings that I can get from findCompletedItemsRequest). This doesn't yield any response either. Can someone please help? I apologize in advance if this is not the proper way to ask a question as this is the first time I am posting one. Thanks.

I am posting the entire code here.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // Turn on all errors, warnings, and notices for easier debugging

// API request variables
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
$query = "shoes";  // Supply your own query keywords as needed

// Create a PHP array of the item filters you want to use in your request
$filterarray =
  array(

   // array(
    //'name' => 'SoldItemsOnly',
    //'value' => 'true')

  );

// Generates an XML snippet from the array of item filters
function buildXMLFilter ($filterarray) {
  global $xmlfilter;
  // Iterate through each filter in the array
  foreach ($filterarray as $itemfilter) {
    $xmlfilter .= "<itemFilter>\n";
    // Iterate through each key in the filter
    foreach($itemfilter as $key => $value) {
      if(is_array($value)) {
        // If value is an array, iterate through each array value
        foreach($value as $arrayval) {
          $xmlfilter .= " <$key>$arrayval</$key>\n";
        }
      }
      else {
        if($value != "") {
          $xmlfilter .= " <$key>$value</$key>\n";
        }
      }
    }
    $xmlfilter .= "</itemFilter>\n";
  }
  return "$xmlfilter";
} // End of buildXMLFilter function

// Build the item filter XML code
buildXMLFilter($filterarray);

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords POST call
// Load the call and capture the response returned by the eBay API
// the constructCallAndGetResponse function is defined below
$resp = simplexml_load_string(constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query, $xmlfilter));

// Check to see if the call was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
  $results = '';  // Initialize the $results variable

  // Parse the desired information from the response
  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
    $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
    $title = $item->title;

    // Build the desired HTML code for each searchResult.item node and append it to $results
    $results .= "<tr><td><img src=\"$pic\"></td><td><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></td></tr>";
  }
}
else {  // If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
  $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
  $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}
?>

<!-- Build the HTML page with values from the call response -->
<html>
<head>
<title>eBay Search Results for <?php echo $query; ?></title>
<style type="text/css">body {font-family: arial, sans-serif;} </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>eBay Search Results for <?php echo $query; ?></h1>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $results;?>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<?php
function constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query, $xmlfilter) {
  global $xmlrequest;

  // Create the XML request to be POSTed
  $xmlrequest  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "<findCompletedItemsRequest xmlns=\"http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services\">\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "<keywords>";
  $xmlrequest .= $query;
  $xmlrequest .= "</keywords>\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "<categoryId>";
  $xmlrequest .= "293";
  $xmlrequest .= "</categoryId>";
  // $xmlrequest .= $xmlfilter;
  //$xmlrequest .= "<paginationInput>\n <entriesPerPage>3</entriesPerPage>\n</paginationInput>\n";
  //$xmlrequest .= "<sortOrder>";
  //$xmlrequest .= "EndTimeSoonest";
  //$xmlrequest .= "</sortOrder>";
  $xmlrequest .= "</findCompletedItemsRequest>";

  // Set up the HTTP headers
  $headers = array(
    'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findCompletedItemsRequest',
    'X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.3.0',
    'X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: XML',
    'X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID: EBAY-US',
    'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: MrinaliL-3ed2-424b-a9e9-599b191e9abe',
    'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8',
  );

  $session  = curl_init($endpoint);                       // create a curl session
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);              // POST request type
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    // set headers using $headers array
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlrequest); // set the body of the POST
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    // return values as a string, not to std out

  $responsexml = curl_exec($session);                     // send the request
  curl_close($session);                                   // close the session
  return $responsexml;                                    // returns a string

}  // End of constructPostCallAndGetResponse function
?>
```

Comment: If you try a curl request through the command line with these parameters, do you get the same result? Can you paste the curl request as well? that'll help us determine if it's an API issue or if its your code.

Comment: I am sorry as I don't really know what curl request through command line means as I am from EE background. Please let me know if this might help you spot the problem .

Comment: A curl request is a command line utility for Linux. It lets you make HTTP requests outside of code.

Comment: Its working with a simple HTTP GET call using name-value pairs. The tip to check the url outside the code did help. Thanks! Though I still couldn't get the one I was using earlier with the HTTP POST (XML request)  starting a cURL session working. Has to be something in the code. Will keep looking!!